# JavaFX: How to use GraphicsContext.fillText?

Tags: java, javafx, canvas

So I'm trying to make a custom Node in my JavaFX application, which extends from the `Canvas` and thus does all its own rendering. I started by simply trying to draw the text "Hello world." on the canvas, but alas it does not appear, even while I can confirm the existence of the custom node in my application via the mouse event handlers.

```java
public class EditorFragment extends Canvas {
    public EditorFragment() {
        super(100, 30);
        this.render(this.getGraphicsContext2D());
        this.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent -> {
            System.out.println("Mouse event occurred in fragment.");
            System.out.println(mouseEvent.toString());
        });
        this.setOnMouseMoved(mouseEvent -> {
            System.out.println("Mouse moved over fragment.");
        });
    }

    protected void render(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.fillText("Hello world.", 0, 0);
    }
}
```

So in short, if I add a new instance of this `EditorFragment` to, let's say, a `Pane`, I know that it is added, and if I would call `gc.fillRect(...)`, I'd see a rectangle showing the node's position and size, but text is not being shown. Why?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently after some more searching, I found that the text was actually being drawn, but that `0, 0` normally corresponds to the bottom-left corner of the text, so it was being drawn above my canvas. To fix this, I changed the render method to the following:

```java
    protected void render(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.setTextAlign(TextAlignment.LEFT);
        gc.setTextBaseline(VPos.CENTER);
        gc.fillText("Hello world.", 0, this.getHeight() / 2);
    }
```